# Running a node js application using webview 2 resulting in localhost is not reachable

Tags: c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net

This is the approach i made in my window application
I have this following function

```
public static Process LaunchProcessApp(string WorkingDirectory, string appExe, string args)
    {
        try
        {

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = appExe, // Replace with the actual path to the npm executable
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,                                        
            };

            if (psi.EnvironmentVariables.ContainsKey("PATH"))
            {
                if (!psi.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"].ToLower().Contains(@"\nodejs\"))
                {
                    string njspath = GetNodejsPathInRegistry();
                    psi.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] += ";" + njspath+";";
                }
                if (!psi.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"].ToLower().Contains(@"\npm\"))
                {
                    string appdatalocalpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData); ;
                    string npmpath = appdatalocalpath + @"Roaming\npm";
                    psi.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] +=   npmpath + ";";
                }                  
            }
            Process p = new Process { StartInfo = psi };
            p.Start();
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd " + WorkingDirectory);                
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(args);
            //p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            //{
            //    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            //    {
            //        MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
            //    }
            //};
            //p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            //p.WaitForExit();
            return p;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.ERROR, "Helpers  --> LanchReactApplication : error:" + ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

on a button click i am running this

```
 bool x = checkIfReactAndNodeIsRunning(56513);
                bool y = checkIfReactAndNodeIsRunning(5000);
                if (!x)
                {
                    string frontendlocation = ThisAddIn.dataFolder + @"FrontEnd";
                    ThisAddIn.clientCodeProcess = LaunchProcessApp(frontendlocation, "cmd", "npm start");
                }
                if (!y)
                {
                    string serverlocation = ThisAddIn.dataFolder + @"Server";
                    ThisAddIn.processTSCode = LaunchProcessApp(serverlocation, "cmd", "npm start");
                }
                if (!x && !y)
                {

                    bgtimer = new Timer();
                    bgtimer.Interval = 3000;
                    bgtimer.Tick += Bgtimer_Tick;
                    bgtimer.Start();
                }



private void Bgtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgtimer.Stop();
        loaderfrm.Close();
        mainFrm.Show();
    }
```

mainForm.cs is the following

```
public MainForm(string args, string title)
    {
        mode = args;
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAsync();
        AttachControlEventHandlers(this.webView21);
        seFormSize();
      
        this.Text = title;                     
    }
private void WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (!e.IsSuccess)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"WebView2 creation failed with exception = {e.InitializationException}");
            CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.ERROR, "Start :: MAINFORM.cs - Function name: WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted - " + e.InitializationException);
            return;
        }          
        this.webView21.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.Image);

        InitBrowser(mode);
    }

private void InitBrowser(string args)
    {
        try
        {
            webView21.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            webView21.Source = new Uri("http://localhost:56513?mode=" + args);
            webView21.Refresh();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.ERROR, "Start :: MAINFORM.cs - Function name: InitBrowser - " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Everything work fine and the process of node and react are working well, but the problem is for a couple of seconds when `webedgeview2` opens it shows that localhost is not reachable and i am guessing is that the process didn't finish executing the `npm start`
is there a way to let the webedgeview to wait until the npm finishes?

Comment: How about not Start/Init the webview until the node server is started?... 
You can read the StandardOutput of Node process and catch "Server listening on 3000" or something like that

Comment: i thought of that but didn't give it a try yet, will do that